# a lot of money (what is a modifier?)

Tags: modifiers

> a lot of money

'of money' modifies 'a lot'? or 'a lot of' modifies 'money'?

a: an indefinite article which modifies a 'noun'

lot: many definitions; one of them: a considerable quantity or extent(a lot of money/lots of friends)

cf. the legs of the table ('of the table' modifies 'the legs' as an adjectival phrase)

Answer (score 0):

*a lot of money*

This is an NP (noun phrase). "Lot" is a non-count quantificational noun functioning as **head** of the NP. The NP is determined (not modified) by the indefinite article "a".

The preposition phrase "of money" functions as complement of "lot".

In your other example, the noun phrase "the legs of the table", "legs" is head and "of the table" is a preposition phrase functioning as its complement.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136495/discussion-on-answer-by-billj-a-lot-of-money-what-is-a-modifier).